# countrycode in R - NA's returned when detecting country name in df

Tags: r, country-codes

I am trying to get the respective continents for a vector of country names in a data frame. I'm using the countrycode package to do so, but keep getting NA's returned as my destination. Example code I'm using:

```
country <- data.frame(country = c("Chile", "Argentina", "Poland"))

country %>%
  mutate(continent = countrycode(sourcevar = 'country', origin = 'country.name', destination = 'region'))
```

I apologize if this is repeated but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly let me know if this is what you were anticipating.

```
country %>%
  mutate(continent = countrycode(sourcevar = country, origin = 'country.name', destination = 'region'))
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense now :)